# PlayFramework: The relation between Controller and Dependencies Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, playframework, controller

Now I am reading PlayFramework's official document which explains DI like this

> There are two ways to make Play use dependency injected controllers.

I can't imagine how they are related, so what do they mean?
Why do we need putting the concept of DI into the Controller?
Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In earlier versions of Play, controllers had static methods.  This in turn lead to lots of either static code or singletons because static controllers couldn't easily share code or service objects.  This also made testing harder than it had to be.

By moving to dependency injected controllers, everything can now be object-based (in place of the earlier class-based approach) and so shared instances or dedicated code can be passed into controllers.

Imagine a app that manages items of some type.  Items are stored in a database, so some configuration is required.

```
public class StaticController extends Controller {
    // active record approach
    public static Result getItems() {
        // static call to Item
        List<Item> items = Item.findAll();
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

When testing this, `StaticController` and `Item` are tightly coupled.  Compare this to an approach using DI, in which a DAO can removed that coupling.

```
public class InjectedController extends Controller {
    private final ItemDao itemDao;

    public InjectedController(final ItemDao itemDao) {
        this.itemDao = itemDao;
    }

    public Result getItems() {
        // static call to Item
        List<Item> items = itemDao.findAll();
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Because `ItemDao` can be an interface, coupling is massively reduced and testing just because a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks. Even though we use a static controller method, we can use it like factory method-wise.  I mean we can write `List<Item> items = Items.use().findAll()` instead of `Item.findAll()` where the `use()` method is a static method and returns just an instance of `Item`. If I implement like this, what is wrong with the app?   Normally I take this approach, so compared with this approach, I want to know the advantages of the approach using DI.

Comment: There's nothing "wrong" with that approach, but `Items.use()` is still a static call and so harder to test, even if it returns an instance of something.  With that approach, you also add an extra layer instead of just injecting the object represented by `Items.use()` directly into the controller.  It also lets you control scope more easily, by allowing for an object-per-request approach.  If you're using actors, you can also inject ActorRefs into controllers, as calling static methods on actors is pointless.

Comment: I thought this question solved, but something uncertain occurred  to me now.    Originally, controller itself is not testable, so I adopt selenium to test it sometimes.  But you said Play introduced the concept of DI into even controllers to make testing easier.   In an usual case, how do you test controller when using `dependency injected controller`?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaTest#unit-testing-controllers and https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaFunctionalTest#injecting-tests